# Returing clause for oracle merge

Tags: oracle, bulk, operation

Does Returing Bulk Collect INTO clause supported in Oracle merge? If no what will be the alternative solution for this problem?

Comment: Try to look here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5318183934935#11942022601143

Comment: No it's not supported. As for workarounds, what would you want the RETURNING clause to return?

Comment: I want all effected  records as collection i.e insert and updated.